# Cannot get vue binding right, resorting to $emit

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

How do I get this example to work with two way binding?

I am creating a file upload component in vue like:

```
window.Vue.component('base64fileupload', {
    template:
        '<input type="file" @change="on_file_changed()"/>',

    methods:
    {
        on_file_changed()
        {
            var self = this;
            var reader = new FileReader();

            var file = this.$el.files[0];
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            reader.onloadend = function (evt)
            {
                if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE)
                {
                    self.$emit('filename', file.name)
                    self.$emit('filedata', evt.target.result)
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and use the following html:

```
<base64fileupload @filename="file_edit.filename = $event"
  @filedata="file_edit.filedata = $event"></base64fileupload>
```

However, that is a bit manual, I expect to be able to bind data instead of using event handlrers. However, `$emit` is the only thing I have got working, despite a lot of testing and googling.

I have tried `data()` and `props` and `self.$forceUpdate()` in numerous ways.

It is not very easy to well why this is not googlable right away, but what I always find is typescript examples and usage of  inside .vue-files, none of which I use.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've a [reactivity issue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), to solve it use the `this.$set` method to mutate the inner fields :

```html
<base64fileupload @filename="$set(file_edit,'filename', $event)"
  @filedata="$set(file_edit, 'filedata', $event)"></base64fileupload>
```

If you want two way binding, you've to define prop named `value` and emit an event called `input` (this valid for vue 2) :

base64fileupload :

```html
window.Vue.component('base64fileupload', {
    template:
        '<input type="file" :value="value" @change="on_file_changed"/>',
    props:['value'],
    methods:
    {
        on_file_changed()
        {
            var self = this;
            var reader = new FileReader();

            var file = this.$el.files[0];
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            reader.onloadend = function (evt)
            {
                if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE)
                {
                    self.$emit('input', {name:file.name, filedat:evt.target.result})
                  
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Use it like :

```html
<base64fileupload v-model="file_edit"></base64fileupload>
```

Comment: The method I already displayed is working, but why do I have to do the event handling manually?

Comment: What do you mean by `the event handling manually`?

Comment: That I need to setup event handlers just to have binding working.

Comment: @AndersLindén please check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own custom FileUpload component and then it could be simpler to just v-model it.

FileUpload.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="file" :value="modelValue" @input="onFileInputChange" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'FileUpload',
  data() {
    return {
      modelValue: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFileInputChange(event) {
      let reader = new FileReader();

      console.log(event.target.files);
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      reader.onloadend = (evt) => {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
          this.$emit('update:modelValue', {
            name: file.name,
            data: evt.target.result,
          });
        }
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Use it like.

```
<FileUpload v-model="file" />
```

Comment: hm, I accepted this first, but it seems I have to convert it to non *.vue.

Comment: Also, the base64 part was thrown away.

Comment: I didn't care about base64 part because the question was more about binding issues. So I rather provided the answer that fits that criteria and assumed you'll take care of the rest, since you already have had the code in place. :)

Comment: I have updated the answer with base64 part.